# Is there a way with HTML to only load the content when you CLICK on a dropdown title?

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so that you click on a title, and a box drops down below it and loads content. I don't want all of the content to load on pageload because it is slowing the site down. Is there any way to do this through HTML? Or maybe CSS?

I'm not as proficient in Javascript or AJAX.
I don't have a base code right now cause I don't really know where to even start...

Comment: Not with pure HTML. You should really look into JavaScript or AJAX for stuff like this.

Comment: look into jQuery .load

Comment: Best thing is use jQuery AJAX, it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with pure HTML and CSS. If you pre loaded the content, you might be able to achieve it with some complex css3. http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Accordion/ is an example. You might have browser compatibility issues however.

The only way to achieve it without preloading the content is with Javascript or JQUERY with AJAX. I'd recommend using Code Academy to learn these technologies. http://www.codecademy.com/learn

Hope this helps

Comment: like BobbleHead's, this should be a comment also.  An answer to this question would be one that provides an html/css solution.  simply telling someone they can't do it should be a comment